# How can stop my cameras outputting to the same render texture in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have two renderer objects (A and B) in my scene connected to two different cameras (green square and red square):

[image: Camera Example]

I am using the following script on both render objects to create a render texure on the corresponding camera and then draw this as a texture on the object on each frame:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

[ExecuteInEditMode]
public class CameraRenderer : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public Camera Camera;
    public Renderer Renderer;

    void Start()
    {
        RenderTexture renderTexture = new RenderTexture (256, 256, 16, RenderTextureFormat.ARGB32);
        renderTexture.Create ();
        Camera.targetTexture = renderTexture;
    }

    void Update () 
    {
        Renderer.sharedMaterial.mainTexture = GetCameraTexture ();
    }

    Texture2D GetCameraTexture()
    {
        RenderTexture currentRenderTexture = RenderTexture.active;
        RenderTexture.active = Camera.targetTexture;
        Camera.Render();
        Texture2D texture = new Texture2D(Camera.targetTexture.width, Camera.targetTexture.height);
        texture.ReadPixels(new Rect(0, 0, Camera.targetTexture.width, Camera.targetTexture.height), 0, 0);
        texture.Apply();
        RenderTexture.active = currentRenderTexture;
        return texture;
    }
}
```

I am expecting to see two different images on A and B from the different cameras, but I am seeing the same image. I originally was using a render texture that I created in the editor attached to the camera, but though that might be what was causing them to render the same thing so I tried creating a new texture on each object. Sadly this still resulted in the same outcome.

I'm pretty new to unity so I've run out of ideas pretty fast - any suggestions would be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't advise naming your objects your class names. Anyways I think the renderers are using the same material and they both render the same texture whichever camera gives them last.

Either use `Renderer.material` to automatically create an new instance of the material, or manually assign different materials to the 2 renderers.

Comment: Yeah it was exactly this - I've accepted this answer as I actually solved it the second way you suggested, by instantiating the original material as I wanted to be able to observe the result in the editor - cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Try,

```
Renderer.material.mainTexture = GetCameraTexture ();
```

Instead of,

```
Renderer.sharedMaterial.mainTexture = GetCameraTexture ();
```